# Can ping NAS by ip and hostname in Windows 10 console, but not find by ip or hostname in Windows explorer

Tags: windows, hostname, server-message-block, console, hosts

I have set up a new PC with Windows 10. Now I want to access two local NAS drives but can't connect to them. With my old PC and all coworkers pcs everything is fine. There is no special access restriction. I also can't see them in the network overview. I am in the same network group and use the same credentials as on my old pc. Weird is that I can connect to our servers harddrive which is no NAS and its within the same network as the NAS.

I can ping it in the console via hostname and ip address but when i try to access it in windows via the explorer it can't be found. I added the ip to the local hosts file, but it didn't solved the problem:

192.168.1.5 NASDAILY

What i found out so far:

ping NASDAILY -n 1 // Is working
ping -6 NASDAILY -n 1 // Not working

On the command "ipconfig /displaydns" i get this:

### nasdaily

Keine Einträge vom Typ AAAA

### nasdaily

Eintragsname . . . . . : NASDAILY

Eintragstyp  . . . . . : 1

Gültigkeitsdauer . . . : 86400

Datenlänge . . . . . . : 4

Abschnitt. . . . . . . : Antwort

(Host-)A-Eintrag  . . : 192.168.1.5

I turned off the pc several times, reset the network connection, turned off firewall, turned of ipv6, nothing helped so far.

Comment: Well you've done a bunch of random things and some things that were redundant. How about turning on Network Discovery on the computer in question?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. I solved the problem in the Windows 10 group policies by allowing unsecure connections, connected to the NAS and then deactivated it again. Now my computer stored the settings.

Comment: remind to accept your own answer